# Devise not rendering correct views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Devise is rendering the sign_in pages that are within the devise gem, not within my app/views path.

its rendering the views from here:
`/Users/c/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb`

routes.rb

`devise_for :users`

How do I have it render under `app/views/users`

Note: ive already generated the devise views using `rails g devise:views users`

this generated a file in `app/views/users` contents are your typical devise folders `sessions, mailer, confirmations, links, etc..`

Comment: 2 years later, and I have the same problem :)

Comment: thats the beauty of stackoverflow

Comment: now go upvote it!!! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are generating views like so `rails generate devise:views users` or 
`rails generate devise:views admins` you need to set

`config.scoped_views = true` in devise initializer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the views that devise uses

Run

```
rails generate devise:views
```

After that, you should be able to modify what devise uses inside the views/devise folder

check out docs [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for more info

Comment: If you modify app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb in your app, does any changes reflect in the browser? sometimes a server restart helps as well.

Comment: Trust me ive restarted my server.  And no when I edit those devise views they do not reflect changes.

Comment: I guess I need a little more information then, did you scope your views in the devise folder? when you ran the generate, did you do `rails generate devise:views users`. The path would then be app/views/devise/users/shared. Then in your config/initializers/devise.rb, you would have to toggle scoped_views to be true. Maybe instead of me guessing your setup, you can update your question again with all the little details that could help with finding the issue like maybe including all the steps you took to get where you are at.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Now I just wonder if you added `config.scoped_views = true` inside config/initializers/devise.rb